# How to use Regex to change groups in string

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to use C# Regex.Replace to automate a manual job of formatting strings in one structure into another. While I am able to identify and replace *one* sub-string, I have been unable to find examples of how to match and replace the rest of the string. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this.

Say I have this search pattern that identifies the string to be transformed:

```
const string inputPattern1 = "SOC.\\d.\\d.\\d.PO \\d";
```

Is it possible to set up replacement rules for each of the parameters?

Here is a visual example of what I mean. Notice in the example that the string has a structure, so it's not a simple case of "replace *any* instance of X with Y".

[image: Desired Regex replace mapping]

This is what I have so far, using a C# console program to work out the methodology.

```
private static void Main()
{
    const string input1 = "SOC.6.1.1.PO 8";
    const string inputPattern1 = "SOC.";
    const string replacement1A = "SSHS-S0";

    // output should be: "SS06-S1C1-08"

    var output1 = Regex.Replace(input1, inputPattern1, replacement1A);

    Console.WriteLine("Input1: {0}",input1);
    Console.WriteLine("Output1: {0}", output1);
}
```

The result is:

```
Input1: SOC.6.1.1.PO 8 
Output1: SSHS-S06.1.1.PO 8
```

Comment: Your replacement string structure is not clear.

Comment: Do you mean the pasted image?

Comment: The `const string replacement1A = "SSHS-S0";` - what is it for?

Comment: It was the string to replace the first input pattern "SOC."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capturing group numbers in your replacement string:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(
    "SOC.6.1.1.PO 8"
,  @"SOC\.(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d)\.PO (\d)"
,   "SS0$1-S$2C$3-0$4"
);
```

`$1` through `$4` represent the content of the input string matched by parenthesized groups.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/6O6oBo)